# Slow third party API requests in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, ruby-on-rails-4, soundcloud, instagram

I'm building a single page Rails 4 app that uses the Soundcloud and Instagram gems. I have noticed that sometimes these API requests slow down my app. I am unsure on what the best approach/practice is for handling such requests so that they do not adversely effect the performance of my app? I've looked into asynchronous requests, sidekiq and have also found this example: http://www.jonb.org/2013/01/25/async-rails.html

My Index Controller looks like this:

```
require 'soundcloud'

class HomeController < ApplicationController

  def index
    # register a new client, which will exchange the username, password for an access_token
    soundcloud_client = Soundcloud.new(
        :client_id => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_ID'],
        :client_secret => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_SECRET'],
        :username => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_USERNAME'],
        :password => ENV['SOUNDCLOUD_PASSWORD']
    )

    # Soundcloud
    @activity = soundcloud_client.get('/me/favorites').first(12)

    # Instagram
    @instagram = Instagram.user_recent_media("1111111", {:count => 12})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe a better approach to this, is to load your index as you would, but do not load the list from soundcloud on that index.

Instead have an Ajax call on your view that calls a pure JSON action inside your controller, doing it that way you will serve the page rapidly, and not block on soundclock. You can put a spinner on  your view indicating that the page is still loading. Looking into jquery load method.

https://api.jquery.com/load/

good luck.